# what xsl to sum elements within date ranges?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

xml excerpt (complete example xml at http://pastebin.com/HDrmzctC ):

```
<log>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>10</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>20</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>10</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>20</money>
    </what>
  </event>

  <event>
    <when>2012-11-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>11</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-11-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>22</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-11-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>11</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-11-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>22</money>
    </what>
  </event>

</log>
```

desired output :
2012-10 food 20
2012-10 beer 40
2012-11 food 22
2012-11 beer 44

or is the xsl not simple because the xml is designed wrong?

Comment: Dan, please, never refer the reader to XML "somewhere". This time I did your work for you -- copied the XML from that destination to the proper place where it belongs -- your question.

Comment: Dimitre, thanks for fixing, i thought it was too big to post.

Comment: Dan, No, it's not too-big. More importantly, the structure is uniform, so it is easy to understand, regardless of the size. The lase places the reader has to look at in order to get all the information for the problem, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kEventByDateItem" match="event"
      use="concat(substring(when, 1,7), '+', what/item)"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "event
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kEventByDateItem',
                       concat(substring(when, 1,7), '+', what/item)
                       )[1]
                  )
      ]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',substring(when, 1,7), ' ', what/item, ' ')"/>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "sum(key('kEventByDateItem',
             concat(substring(when, 1,7), '+', what/item)
             )/what/money)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<log>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>10</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>20</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>10</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-10-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>20</money>
    </what>
  </event>

  <event>
    <when>2012-11-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>11</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-11-26T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>22</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-11-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>food</item>
      <money>11</money>
    </what>
  </event>
  <event>
    <when>2012-11-27T21:32:52</when>
    <what>
      <item>beer</item>
      <money>22</money>
    </what>
  </event>

</log>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
2012-10 food 20
2012-10 beer 40
2012-11 food 22
2012-11 beer 44
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** with composite key.